# Using App::uses (instead of App::import) in a CakePHP 2.1 Plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I'm writing a small application in CakePHP 2.1, and I want to use Nick Baker's file upload plugin. I downloaded the cakephp2.0 branch (I know that isn't done yet), and placed it in my apps Plugin folder. I made some necessary modifications on it, but I'm curious what the right way is to replace those `App::import` function calls (at start of `FileUploadComponent`, `FileUploadBehavior` and `FileUploadHelper` classes) with the `App:uses` function.

It needs to import the `FileUploadSettings` class from Config/file_upload_settings.php and the `Uploader` class from Vendor/upload.php. It can be done with the `require_once` function, but I'm sure there is a CakePHP way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Cake manual `App::import()` is comparable to the way `require_once()` works. From what I understand you would load classes using `App:uses()` and Vendor files using `App:import()`.

The API documentation says [the following](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App::import) on the subject:

> All classes that were loaded in the past using `App::import(‘Core’, $class)` will need to be loaded using `App::uses()` referring to the correct package. This change has provided large performance gains to the framework.
>
> - The method no longer looks for classes recursively, it strictly uses
>     the values for the paths defined in `App::build()`
> - It will not be able to load `App::import('Component', 'Component')` use `App::uses('Component', 'Controller');`.
> - Using `App::import('Lib', 'CoreClass');` to load core classes is no longer possible. Importing a non-existent file, supplying a wrong type or package name, or `null` values for `$name` and `$file` parameters will result in a false return value.
> - `App::import('Core', 'CoreClass')` is no longer supported, use `App::uses()` instead and let the class autoloading do the rest.
> - Loading Vendor files does not look recursively in the vendors folder, it will also not convert the file to underscored anymore as it did in the past.

The migration guide also has [some things to say](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#class-loading-with-app-uses) about `App:uses()` and is a good starting point in general to compare best practices for 2.0 with the older methods from 1.3 and lower.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158129/loading-vendor-files-in-cakephp-2-0) deals with loading Vendor files in Cake 2.0, I can't verify the claim by José Lorenzo that `App:import()` is a "silly wrapper" for `require_once()`, nor the statement that it's the preferred way of including files. The only reference I could find for the latter is in the [Coding Standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html) for Cake contributors, viz. developers contributing to the Cake core, not applications built on the framework.

**EDIT**

Let's say you want to import the [Twitter OAuth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth), residing in `Vendor/twitter`, the main class file is `twitteroauth.php` in `Vendor/twitter/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php`:

```
  App::import('Vendor', 'twitteroauth', array('file' => 'twitter'.DS.'twitteroauth'.DS.'twitteroauth.php'));
```

Answer (score 28):

From what I've gathered:

- use `import()` for external libraries
- and `uses()` for framework files

For example:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'ExternalLibrary');
App::uses('Inflector', 'Cake.Utility');
```