# Unit testing runs two tests, "Cannot declare class, because the name is already in use"

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, require

guys. I have two Unit Tests Classes in CakePhp:

```
<?php
App::import('Vendor/Laravel', 'Api');
class UserApi extends LaravelApi {
```

And

```
<?php
App::uses('Api', 'Vendor/Laravel');
App::import('Vendor/Laravel', 'Api');
App::import('Component', 'Session');
class LaravelApiTest extends CakeTestCase {
```

When I run my unit test (I will call it AllApp.php) that should run these two tests (and some other too), I get the message

```
Fatal Error Error: Cannot declare class LaravelApi, because the name is already in use in [/var/www/html/app/Vendor/Laravel/Api.php, line 9]
```

I have tried by removing one of the two App:import('Vendor/Laravel', 'Api'); and "AllApp.php" runs fine, but of course, the individual test I modified fails because:

```
Error: Class 'LaravelApi' not found
```

I think it is because these two files are not run at the same time when I run the individual test, but when I run them with "AllApp" the two files are loaded and the class gets "required" two times (even thought I think App::import is similar to "require_once"). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using App::uses (instead of App::import) in a CakePHP 2.1 Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994514/using-appuses-instead-of-appimport-in-a-cakephp-2-1-plugin)

Comment: I have already checked that, no it doesn't. but Thank you very much.

Comment: Cake loves to wrap things that don't need it. They still have `up()` that just calls `strtoupper`? Sure does sound like a `include` over `include_once`.  Not clear how the autoload works here or if there even is autoloading. If not then even the order of those import/uses becomes important.

Comment: meh, I guess I will go with a good old "require_once" then, it seems to work. Thank you guys anyway.

Comment: `if(!class_exists('LaravelApi')) { App::import(...); }`

Comment: Thank you very much Greg, but require_once would not require the "if" line, so I would rather that.