# CakePHP - Klarna API - Installing & running an external app PHP API

Tags: php, api, cakephp

I think this question relates to most PHP API's you download and run in your application. I want to integrate the [Klarna API](http://integration.klarna.com/en/api/standard-integration) with my  CakePHP application. Now, I am not a very seasoned CakePHP programmer so my questions might be very rudimentary. But I haven't figured this out conceptually, how it works with external non-CakePHP software in a CakePHP app. Basically how do I set it up and use it.

1. In which folder do I put the Klarna files in my CakePHP app? Webroot?
2. To initialise and configure the Klarna API for use, do I simply put the Klarna code in the controller without messing about with any of the CakePHP component / plugin load procedures?
3. Do I then run the API code in the controller as well?
4. I don't need to be using cURL to talk to Klarna in this case right? The Klarna API will make the call to Klarna's servers itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have received testing login credentials from Klarna, this is a working example:

1. Download the PHP API from Klarna. The files should be placed in the "/Vendors" folder as per
   [Loading Vendor Files in CakePHP 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158129/loading-vendor-files-in-cakephp-2-0)
   & [App Class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html), I put them in a folder named "klarna" for the sake
   of organising things. Klarna API consists of quite a few files so
   can be a good idea.
2. You'll initialise and setup the API in the relevant
   controller, or I did at least. To load the vendor files do:
   App::import('Vendors, 'klarna/klarna');. Given CakePHP's folder structure, I had to modify a couple of lines from the .getAddresses file example. One was previously '/transport/xmlrpc-3.0.0.beta/lib/xmlrpc.inc', became '/vendors/klarna/transport/xmlrpc-3.0.0.beta/lib/xmlrpc.inc'. Similar for the one two lines below. Remember to set the test-accounts "Shared secret" and "merchant ID" as well as having the right test-server configured. Then you can test the API against one of Klarna's test persons.
3. Yes, the configuration and execution of the Klarna API both happens
   in the controller as per examples. It's just normal PHP code though.
4. We don't need to be using cURL for this API. The API takes care of the calls itself.