# cakephp 2.1.0 Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found

Tags: cakephp-2.0, dompdf

I followed [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/11/21/serving-views-as-files-in-cake2/) great tutorial

My `View/Layouts/pdf/default.ctp`

```
App::import('Vendor', 'dompdf/dompdf.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($content_for_layout), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->output();
```

My `View/Bids/pfd/view.ctp` is a copy of my regular view for testing purposes.

If I remove php extension:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'dompdf/dompdf');
```

I get error:

```
An input file is required (i.e. input_file _GET variable).
```

Tried several combinations of require_once as well to no luck.
(Even tried with another dompdf fresh download: (from [Github](https://github.com/dompdf), zip called dompdf-master)

```
App::import('Vendor', 'dompdf-master/dompdf.php');
```

and got same Class not found error.

If I remove php extension in this dompdf-master

```
App::import('Vendor', 'dompdf-master/dompdf');
```

got error:

```
PHP-font-lib must either be installed via composer or copied to lib/php-font-lib
```

I'm positive access is granted and files are where they are supposed to be, php 5.3.

It's supposed to be very simple according to mark's tutorial.

Can you help?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I suggest you test with standard PHP include() to get everything working first.  Then start replacing the includes one at a time with Cake's App::import.  (the syntax for the various Cake include/import/etc methods can be unintuitive and plain wonky)

Comment: Thank you @Costa; tried `include(APP . 'Vendor/dompdf/dompdf.php');' and got error `An input file is required (i.e. input_file _GET variable).'. Tried including each .php file (dompdf_config.inc.php, etc) and same error.  Removing .php extension gives no class found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct file to load for setting up dompdf is dompdf_config.inc.php. dompdf does not currently follow the [CakePHP File and Classname Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-classname-conventions). Since you're loading the class directly instead of using a plugin that utilizes dompdf you'll have to be more explicit. Looking at the [App::import() documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#including-files-with-app-import) in the CakePHP book, something like the following might work:

```
App::import($type = 'Vendor', 'DOMPDF', true, array(), 'dompdf_config.inc.php', false);
```

Of course, if you [follow the advice in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8158269/264628), you should just use require:

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php');
```

Finally, I recommend you drop the `utf8_decode()` call, so long as you're using dompdf 0.6.0. dompdf 0.5.1 didn't handle UTF8 too well, but the latest release handles it just fine, so long as you've followed the advice in the [Unicode How-to](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo).

Your layout should thus look more like the following:

```
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($content_for_layout);
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->output();
```

Comment: Thank you #BrianS. The class now seems to load.
However, Adobe reports error:
File does not begin with '%PDF-'.
Local\EWH-jlr[+$y

I'm using Adobe Reader X, tried unchecking 'Display PDF in browser', cleaned on browser history, etc.
Any ideas on how to fix?
(Aside from that, another pdf generator (mpdf) works great outside cakephp, just couldn't integrate into cake, but the pdf is created flawless).  I've also read that this error happens when data is posted before the pdf is rendered. Any hint on that? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you @BrianS. he class now seems to load. However, Adobe reports error: File does not begin with '%PDF-'. Local\EWH-jlr[+$y I'm using Adobe Reader X, tried unchecking 'Display PDF in browser', cleaned on browser history, etc. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: Just tried this plugin which uses dompdf (or Mpdf) https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf  and still got error: File does not begin with '%PDF-'. !!  Can you help?

Comment: You may have some kind of PHP errors or CakePHP debug info being sent in addition to the PDF. Make sure your CakePHP debug level is set to 0 by adding `Configure::write('debug',0);` to the top of your layout.

Comment: FYI, to see if non-PDF content is making its way into the output you can open your PDF in a plain text editor (such as Notepad or TextEdit). The non-PDF content will usually be at the top of the file.

Comment: It works now! Used dompdf and layout as suggested by @BrianS. Thank you so much for the tips. Was able to see as text file and removed undesired output via `ob_end_clean();` as the last line on my controller action.